# Install a PKCS#12 Certificate into firefox from the command line

Tags: firefox, certificate, certutil

I am trying to use certutil to add a **client certificate** to the firefox db:
The purpose of this certificate is to authenticate with a server - the server asks for credentials, this certificate contains the credentials.

```
certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d /myfirefoxprofile/ -t "CT,," -a -i /mycertificate.pfx
```

However this gives me the error:

```
certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message.
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

This is on ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Why not import the certificate using Firefox GUI ?

Comment: i have had to tackle this before...it's way easier to require a user to run a certificate generation and import script(click here or bundle it in an installer) to identify themselves to a web-app than it is to have a 10+ click 2 page installation document with screenshots

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to convert PFX to PEM...directions with openssl switches here: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106028

to be clear as evidently somehow i was confusing:

convert from pfx to pem then rerun your import command with the new file(edit: and the modified options below). it looks to me like the firefox cert import is choking on the pfx filetype(edit: and the appropriate import options were not specified).  the directions linked to are not for firefox import, but for certificate conversion.

additional edit after question edit:

the -t needs the u option to be used as a client certificate.  the -u flag needs the C option...certutil flags are documented here: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html

you may also want to look here: http://www.phocean.net/2008/11/16/how-to-stop-firefox-from-prompting-for-the-client-certificate.html
as the browser may prompt on using the certificate

certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d /myfirefoxprofile/ -t "CTu,," -u "c" -a -i /mycertificate.pem

should do it

Comment: How does this help with adding the certificate to firefox?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: When I import the pem file that was generated the certificate shows up as an authority but NOT as a certificate that can be used to identify me.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do...i thought you were trying to add your cert as a CA so you could force firefox to trust additional sites with self signed keys, clarify question plz

Comment: Updated question

Comment: updated answer as well.  by default certs are imported as CAs.  you have to tell the tool you want to use it for other purposes

Comment: This still didn't work :( - certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: security library: invalid arguments. I tried the whole process from scratch again with no luck

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I imported a client certificate into an empty Firefox profile:

```
# convert pem and key file into a pkcs12
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /path/my-cert.pem -inkey /path/my-cert.key -out /tmp/my-cert.p12 

# create empty directory
mkdir /tmp/empty_profile

# populate dir with certificate databases
certutil -N -d sql:/tmp/empty_profile

# import p12 file into database
pk12util -d sql:/tmp/empty_profile -i /tmp/mycert.p12 -n my-cert-nickname
```